# Prevent local site css and js from overriding remotely served Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, unique

**Background:** We are serving several Bootstrap modals from our **remote** domain to multiple **local** websites (all with different owners, different css, etc.) via local site links to our remote javascript and css.

The goal is for our remotely served modals to have consistent and reasonably controllable appearance across all such local sites.

**The problem:** The styling of any remotely served modal that loads within a local site can (and will) be affected by the js and css of that local site, and since Bootstrap is so widely implemented, we are encountering lots of problems with the appearance and behavior of our modals on virtually every site where they will be used.

We have already renamed our bootstrap filenames and virtually every class and ID in our modal designs to use a unique prefix, but there are still styling conflicts that create display and behavior problems on those local sites.

**The question:**

> Is there a recommended method for modifying our Bootstrap js and css to give every possible function and style element a unique prefix (without breaking Bootstrap) ... so that when our remote modals are loaded inside a local site, the local site's existing implementation of Bootstrap will not override our styling and functions?
>
> Or is there maybe another way to solve the problem described?

(Note: We cannot load our js and css last on the local sites' pages because we don't want our remote js and css to override the local sites' existing styling, either. We also have no control over the local sites' local css, so we can't create a single css for their content and ours.)

Comment: _"We also have no control over the local sites' local css"_ --> Then you _can't_ prevent local sites from breaking your styling.

Comment: Time to go back to the drawing board? If the local site can create whatever CSS selectors they want and will always come after your selectors then you are at the local site's mercy. Prefixing should help but if they're still being overridden on a local site then you will likely need to increase the specificity of those selectors and possibly use the dreaded `!important`.

Comment: So sounds like someone needs to use iframes...

Comment: We considered iframes, which looked promising, but we are utilizing some js functions inside our modals that must interact with the local site and are hard (impossible?) to implement across sites from inside an iframe. iframes also present new display and sizing challenges. But it's a good thought.

Comment: @hungerstar -- Prefixing has helped a lot already, but we've been doing it sort of piecemeal, and there must be things we're missing. For example, we haven't managed to rename "modal" itself without breaking Bootstrap functionality. So, we're thinking there must be a more methodical and comprehensive way to generate a unique iteration of Bootstrap js and css.

Comment: You could use iframe and still interact with the main site, you would just have to implement [postMessage api](http://viget.com/extend/using-javascript-postmessage-to-talk-to-iframes) use on the page loaded in the iframe and in the script loaded on the local site. The only other option would be to use shadow Dom/Web Components but i believe it is tricky currently to get bootstrap to work with them well.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans. postMessage api looks very useful.